# Maven: Unzip nested zip files.

Tags: java, maven

I am struggling to extract contents of nested zip file in an artifact.

```
Artifact has below content zipped: 

Base_Config.zip
       First_Pack.zip
             01_first.json
             02_second.json
       Second_Pack.zip
             01_third.json
             02_fourth.json

able to extract only zip files under Base_config.zip not it's contents *.json
`<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.shashank.bss.XXX</groupId>
                                <artifactId>testdatagen</artifactId>
                                <version>24.5.0</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>target/assemble/shashank/deps</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>testdatagen-*-First_Pack.zip</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

`

Tried multiple solution: 
Failed to get content using assembly descriptor,

Tried solution available on this as well:
[Custom maven assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493381/custom-maven-assembly)

Not want to use deprecated plugin and the solution available there with plugin: 
truezip-maven-plugin
[Unpack inner zips in zip with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264064/unpack-inner-zips-in-zip-with-maven)

Is it possible to get the work done by this plugin: 
maven-dependency-plugin & unpack.

Or any other simple solution available from maven?

Comment: What would be the expected directory structure?

Comment: Hi Tunaki, 

<outputDirectory>target/assemble/shashank/deps</outputDirectory>                                       
Wanted few json files to be extracted in this directory.

Comment: @shashank makkar you commented about truezip-maven-plugin but put a link related to maven-antrun-plugin. I am not sure maven-antrun-plugin is deprecated, and it does the work, so ...

Comment: @alainlompo 
Actually i mentioned both. 
 Ant plugin which has been deprecated &  truezip-maven-plugin solution (that was in comments by @palacsint) 

I tried with Ant plugin, it did not worked out. 
Can you share the way i can achieve:
to download the artifact from a different project which has nested zip as described and extract inner-most json

Comment: Possible ducplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264064/unpack-inner-zips-in-zip-with-maven

Comment: @Linuslabo 
Problem statement is same and  I have highlighted this link in my problem statement as well

Solution available there is using ant plugin where src file is part of project resource. 

In my project i have to download the zip use maven-dependency-plugin then then need to extract contents of inner zip. 
For this, any suggestion will be helpful at any point of time.

Comment: @Shashank have you given a look at other solutions as well? (`maven-dependency-plugin` and `truezip-maven-plugin`)

Comment: Yup,    maven-dependency-plugin didn't failed to extract inner zip file contents. 
Can't use truezip, i think it only works when you have source file (zip) available in your project.

Comment: The org.apache.portals.jetspeed-2:jetspeed-unpack-maven-plugin might be another option.